# Show $C^\prime $ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group. Let $C^\prime =\{ a\in G:(ax)^2=(xa)^2 \;\forall x\in G \}$. Prove $C^\prime$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I could easily show it for a similar problem but instead with $ax=xa$. I am trying to show that $C^\prime$ is closed under products and inverses. Here's what I have tried for the first:

Closed under products:

Let $a,b \in C$. We want to show that $(abx)^2=(xab)^2$, to show that $ab\in C^\prime$.

We know that $(ax)^2=(xa)^2 $ and $(bx)^2=(xb)^2$.

$$(abx)^2=abxabx=(x^{-1}x)abxabx=(x^{-1})xabxabx=x^{-1}(xab)^2 x$$

This is where I got stuck. How can I eliminate those first and last terms and complete this?

Also, for inverses:

Let $a\in C$. We want to show $a^{-1}\in C^\prime$.

I'm pretty much stuck on inverses.

Please give some advice. I am looking for hints, not full solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that $(abx)^2=(ay)^2$ with $y=bx$.

[The property that $(ax)^2=(xa)^2$ is true for all $x \in G$!]

Comment: Aha! If $b,x\in G$ then $y=bx\in G$. Let $z=xa$. Clearly, $z\in G$ because $a,x\in G$, so: $(abx)^2=(ay)^2=(ya)^2=(bxa)^2=(bz)^2=(zb)^2=(xab)^2$. Therefore, $C^\prime$ is closed under products. Thank you!

Comment: @Seirios, +1 Beautifully crafted hint!

Comment: Agreed. Thanks!

Comment: Still struggling with the inverse for this problem. I am trying to show that $(a^{-1}x)^2=(xa^{-1})^2$.

Comment: Notice that the equality is equivalent to $(x^{-1}a)^2=(ax^{-1})^2$ and apply the same argument as above.